# Is there a way to set req.connection_timeout for specific requests in Varnish?

Tags: varnish

I've got a Varnish setup sitting in front of PHP machines. For 98% of pages, a single request timeout (`req.connect_timeout` in VLC) works. I've got a couple pages, however, that we expect to take up to 3 minutes before they should timeout. Is there a way to set req.connection_timeout for specific requests in Varnish? If so, please show me the light in VCL. I'd like to keep the same `req.connect_timeout` for all pages but raise that number for these few specific pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think connection_timeout limit the time for setting up the connection to the back-end, and first_byte_timeout and between_bytes_timeout limit the processing time. Have you tried setting the bereq.first_byte_timeout programmatically in vcl_recv? E.g. with something like:

```
backend mybackend {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 100ms;
  .first_byte_timeout = 5s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 5s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
  set req.backend = mybackend;
  if ( req.url ~ "/slowrequest" ) {
    # set req.connect_timeout = 180s; # old naming convention?
    set bereq.connect_timeout = 180s;
  }
  # .. do default stuff
}
```

Let me know if it works...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly, this does not work for varnish > 3

Very sad. There does not seem to be a way to actually achieve this in v>3.0
Banging my head since hours on this issue.

I now do have a solution:

Use vcl_miss!

Here is an example:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend = director_production;
    if (req.request == "POST") {
            return(pipe);
    }
    else {          
            return(lookup);
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
  if (req.url ~ "/longrunning") {
            set bereq.first_byte_timeout = 1h; # one hour!
            set bereq.between_bytes_timeout = 10m;
  } else {
            set bereq.first_byte_timeout = 10s;
            set bereq.between_bytes_timeout = 1s;
  }
}
```

This works for me. 
What got me worried was that the documentation of varnish states that vcl_miss is always called when am object is not found in the cache. In my first version I ommited the if/else in vcl_recv. I then had to experience (once again) that somehow the documentation is wrong. One needs to explicitly state the "return(lookup)". Otherwise vcl_miss is not called. :(

Comment: I get: `'bereq.first_byte_timeout': cannot be set in method 'vcl_miss'.` in varnish 5.2.1 so this does not seem to work (anymore).

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it by declaring multiple backends in Varnish, each with a different timeout - but probably refering to the very same IP and server. Then you can simply set a new backend for certain URLs, to force them to use the timeouts declared there.

```
if (req.url ~ "[something]") {
     set req.backend = backend_with_higher_timeout;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In VCL 4.0 you can define your backend and give varnish hint to use it:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "POST" && req.url ~ "^/admin") {
        set req.backend_hint = backend_admin_slow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vcl_backend_fetch and set the timeout there:

`sub vcl_backend_fetch {
  if (bereq.method == "POST" && bereq.url == "/slow") {
    set bereq.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
  }
}`